# Javascript Iterate over chunk/grouped array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Am in a situation, where i have an array with thousands of items,
first i break this array into groups of chunks 1000 per each, then i call a function which processes the first chunk in the array and it returns the new grouped chunks.

```
// Using lodash
var array = []; // my array with many items
var ids = _.chunk(array, 1000); // grouped array 1000 each

function LoopArrayGroups(ids){

  var arrSize = _.size(ids); // number of groups

  if(arrSize != 0){
    // get First group array,remove it from the list
    var toBeUsed = ids[0];
    ids.splice(0, 1);

    //process first group 
    myFunction(toBeUsed, function(promise){

      if(!promise.error){

        // return new array with the first group removed
        return ids;

      }else{
        console.log("Some error " + promise.error);
      }

    });

  }
}
```

The LoopArrayGroups method is called with an array of grouped chunks then it processes the first chunk, removes it then returns new grouped chunks ,

**I just want to loop through the group arrays until they become empty. instead of calling this function over and over again**

Comment: "*i know there is a much more simpler way to do this*" - I don't even know what problem you're trying to solve, but if you **know there's a simpler/better way**, use that instead.

Comment: @Tuna question is not clear at all.

Comment: Does myFunction return a promise? Are you trying to delay the second iteration of the loop until the first promise has resolved?

Comment: @Douglas yes myFunction returns a promise, until the promise it returned the loop will not continue. So after the promise is returned i go to the next value in the grouped items.

Comment: Could you provide the code of `myFunction`?

Comment: Does `myFunction` do something with the callback return value? You do `return ids;`, but unless `myFunction` has ways to populate a global variable, there is little use in returning anything.

Comment: @trincot myFunction is an HTTP request it returns success or error, it doesn't populate any global variable, i will go with your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
return ids;
```

call the main function again:

```
LoopArrayGroups(ids);
```

#### Remark

The recursive call will increase the use of the stack on each call on most environments, because currently not many JavaScript engines have implemented the tail-recursion optimisation.

Practically this means that if you have a *huge* amount of chuncks, you could run into stack overflow errors. If this is a concern, you should alter the recursive call to make it asynchronous:

```
setTimeout(LoopArrayGroups.bind(ids), 0);
```

As you already have asynchronous processing in `myFunction`, there is in fact no downside in doing it this way.

Comment: So you mean in my first call i should do it like this `setTimeout(LoopArrayGroups.bind(ids), 0);`

Comment: The very first call can stay like it is (it does not matter either way), this is only really useful in the recursive call made inside the  `myFunction` callback. Just be aware that any code following your initial call cannot assume that everything has been done, because the whole process is asynchronous and will happen later.